# does gi work in windows?

Tags: python, gtk, gobject-introspection

After days of research on stackoverflow and the web and trying imports and installs using pip, pacman, MSYS2, python -m, and researching here, I have concluded that gtk, gi.repository is not ready for windows just yet.  So I am looking for another library that will help me arrange pictures in a grid that i can then drag and drop to switch their position in the grid.  If I am wrong about gi working on windows, please explain how to install it! Here is the sample code that I wanted to start with.  I am using vscode as an ide, so I'm not sure how that fits in.  Most similar posts are specific to linux rather than windows.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
class FlowBoxWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="FlowBox Demo")
        self.set_border_width(10)
        self.set_default_size(300, 250)

        header = Gtk.HeaderBar(title="Flow Box")
        header.set_subtitle("Sample FlowBox app")
        header.props.show_close_button = True

        self.set_titlebar(header)

        scrolled = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        scrolled.set_policy(Gtk.PolicyType.NEVER, Gtk.PolicyType.AUTOMATIC)

        flowbox = Gtk.FlowBox()
        flowbox.set_valign(Gtk.Align.START)
        flowbox.set_max_children_per_line(30)
        flowbox.set_selection_mode(Gtk.SelectionMode.NONE)

        self.create_flowbox(flowbox)

        scrolled.add(flowbox)

        self.add(scrolled)
        self.show_all()

    def color_swatch_new(self, str_color):
        color = Gdk.color_parse(str_color)

        rgba = Gdk.RGBA.from_color(color)
        button = Gtk.Button()

        area = Gtk.DrawingArea()
        area.set_size_request(24, 24)
        area.override_background_color(0, rgba)

        button.add(area)

        return button

    def create_flowbox(self, flowbox):
        colors = [
        'AliceBlue',
        'AntiqueWhite',
        'AntiqueWhite1',
        'AntiqueWhite2',
        'AntiqueWhite3',
        'AntiqueWhite4',
        'aqua',
        'aquamarine',
        'aquamarine1',
        'aquamarine2',
        'aquamarine3',
        'aquamarine4',
        'azure',
        'azure1',
        'azure2',
        'azure3',
        'azure4',
        'beige',
        'bisque',
        'bisque1',
        'bisque2',
        'bisque3',
        'bisque4',
        'black',
        'BlanchedAlmond',
        'blue',
        'blue1',
        'blue2',
        'blue3',
        'blue4',
        'BlueViolet',
        'brown',
        'brown1',
        'brown2',
        'brown3',
        'brown4',
        'burlywood',
        'burlywood1',
        'burlywood2',
        'burlywood3',
        'burlywood4',
        'CadetBlue',
        'CadetBlue1',
        'CadetBlue2',
        'CadetBlue3',
        'CadetBlue4',
        'chartreuse',
        'chartreuse1',
        'chartreuse2',
        'chartreuse3',
        'chartreuse4',
        'chocolate',
        'chocolate1',
        'chocolate2',
        'chocolate3',
        'chocolate4',
        'coral',
        'coral1',
        'coral2',
        'coral3',
        'coral4'
        ]

        for color in colors:
            button = self.color_swatch_new(color)
            flowbox.add(button)


win = FlowBoxWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: ok i removed that part!

Comment: You didn't post any error? PyGObject itself works fine.

Comment: Step 1: Install python 3.4 or older. Step 2: Install [PyGObject for Windows](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/) and don't forget to check "Gtk+" during the installation.

Comment: oh? so 3.5 won't work? I know i installed PyGObject, but I was confused by all the installation options. Maybe i didn't check gtk+.  I'll uninstall - and if it still doesn't work, I'll install earlier python

Comment: 3.4.x? or 3.4 exact?

Comment: @MrMulti I've personally used exactly python 3.4; I'm not sure if 3.4.x is also supported.

Comment: @Rawing 3.4 works- I'm leaving as is .  thanks!